# Parsing messages on EC2 logs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to analyse EC2 logs on cloudwatch.

I have no problem on moving them somewhere (like S3) but the format is quite complex. Each file contains several units with the structure showed below. Each one of these units have a "logEvents" list with many events. The challenge is to parse the "message" part of the event to get something meaningful out of it.

Ideally I'd like to transform the "json" below into a relation format with columns "loGroup", "logStream", "timestamp", "securityID", "AccountName"... and so on.
Any idea on how to do that?

```
{
    "messageType": "DATA_MESSAGE",
    "owner": "111111111111",
    "logGroup": "loggroup-test",
    "logStream": "i-stream",
    "logEvents": [
    {
        "id": "34324324324324324324354354354354354354354354354354354354325",
        "timestamp": 1541152802821,
        "message": "[Security] [INFORMATION] [23213] [Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing] [A logon was attempted using explicit credentials.

        Subject:
            Security ID:        XXXXX
            Account Name:       XXXXX$
            Account Domain:     XX
            Logon ID:       0xXXX
            Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

        Account Whose Credentials Were Used:
            Account Name:       XXXXXXX
            Account Domain:     XXX.XXXX
            Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

        (more info here...)
       "-->end of the "message"
    },
    {
    "another log event"
    },
    {
    "another log event"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? Do you not know how to retrieve them from CloudWatch or S3, or do you not know how to parse JSON using Python, or is it something else?